# Update check-boxes status with visibility change

Tags: android, checkbox, visibility

I am having check boxes to control the visibility  of different views. When check box status is changed similarly visibility is changed, which is working fine. In my app views visibility also changes on different user input. I want to update checkbox status if visibility of view change by any way. Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put

```
checkbox.setChecked(true);
```

anywhere that you call

```
someView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

There is no way AFAIK that you can inherently "watch" the visibility state, you have to active set the checked state at the same time that you change the visibility state.

Comment: Ok. I mean in silver light we can bind two objects, is there any thing like that in android.

Comment: maybe onGlobalLayoutChange callback in this object: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html not sure how you set it up, but that might help you achieve a listener type setup for the visibility state.